# Setting minSdkVersion and available emulators?

Tags: android, eclipse

Today I upgraded to SDK version 3.0 from 2.3.3. I have one question that has always puzzled me.

My code is unchanged from when I built it with build target API level 7, so there are no API level methods called. I've now changed the Properties/build target to API level 11 but set the minSdkVersion  to level 7 in the manifest.

When I set up a run configuration under Eclipse, the only AVDs available to me are level 11. Should not the level 7 AVDs (which do exist on my machine) be available as targets?

If not, what use is setting the minSdkVersion to 7, as I can't test it on a level 7 emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Debug configuration panel for your app, you have to go to the Target Tab and change the  Deployment Target Selection Mode to 'Manual' and once you click on Debug button, you'll get a "Android Device Chooser" dialog where you can specify which AVD to startup.

Comment: Well done!  I'd tried the manual option, got as far as seeing what devices I could choose from  and given up when all I could see was the level 11 device. I never thought that hitting 'run' or 'debug' would bring up all the others. The plugin definitely needs improving in this respect. Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Comment: Note that if you have an Android device plugged in while attempting this you may still see "No AVD Available". Unplug your device, open the Android Device Chooser again, and you will see your emulators listed.